# PHPStorm can't add a remote interpreter for debugging

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm new to PhpStorm and I'm trying to configure the remote server for debugging. We have a server running PHP 5.2.11 that we need to maintain. Can I even set up a 5.2 Interpreter? PhpStorm 8 seems to only support 5.3 and up? I connect to the server via SSH and get 'Interpreter doesn't exist on remote server' when I point to the PHP root.

I have configured XDebug/PHPStorm both server side and on my IDE machine but I'm assuming debugging will not be possible without properly configuring the Interpreter?

Comment: PHP 5.2 is indeed not supported natively anymore by PhpStorm. And considering that this version is [over 5 years old](http://php.net/releases/index.php#5.2.11), you may want to (insist on your client to) consider upgrading.